# Why is OCR1B values are not stored?

Tags: avr, atmega, pwm, servo

I have following program to control two servo motors:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>

void main()
{  
  int x,i,j,t=0,y=0,n=0;
  DDRA=0b11111111;
  DDRC=0b11111111;
  DDRB=0b00001111;

  //Configure TIMER1
  TCCR1A|=(1<<COM1A1)|(1<<COM1B1)|(1<<WGM11);         //NON Inverted PWM
  TCCR1B|=(1<<WGM13)|(1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS11)|(1<<CS10);  //PRESCALER=64 MODE 14(FAST PWM)

  ICR1=2499;  //fPWM=50Hz (Period = 20ms Standard).

  DDRD|=(1<<PD4)|(1<<PD5);    //PWM Pins as Out

  OCR1A=65;
  OCR1B=50;

  unsigned int k[1],z[1];

  while (1) {
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++) { //for keypad
      PORTB=0xf7>>i| 0xf0;
      x=PINB;

      if (x==0b11101110) {  //key 1 for moving motor 1
        OCR1A=OCR1A+1;
        _delay_ms(100);
      } else if (x==0b11011110) { //key 2 for moving motor 2
        OCR1B=OCR1B+1;
        _delay_ms(100);
      } else if(x==0b10111110) {    //key 3 for storing value of OCR1A
        k[t]=OCR1A;
        t++;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        _delay_ms(1000);              
      } else if (x==0b11101101) {    //key 4 for storing value of OCR1B
        z[n]=OCR1B;
        n++;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        _delay_ms(1000);
      } else if (x==0b11011101) {   //key 5 for moving motor from k[0] to k[1]
        OCR1A=k[0];
        Wait();
        for(OCR1A=k[0];OCR1A<=k[1];OCR1A++) _delay_ms(100);
        _delay_ms(1000); 
      } else if (x==0b10111101) {    //key 6 for moving motor from z[0] to z[1]
        OCR1B=z[0];
        Wait();
        for(OCR1B=z[0];OCR1B<=z[1];OCR1B++) _delay_ms(100);
        _delay_ms(1000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have 4*3 Keypad connected port B. Both motors work properly through keys, but while storing only values of OCR1A are stored properly and somehow OCR1B values are not stored properly. Is there any difference between functioning of OCR1A and OCR1B?

After moving motors I am storing the values of OCR1A and OCR1B which represent their current positions. I am storing those values in array (k[] and z[]). Keys 5 and 6 are used to access the values stored earlier so that I can move the motors between the two positions.

Comment: What do you mean by "storing". Minimize your code to the bare minimum to reproduce the issue.

Comment: After moving motors I am storing values of OCR1A and OCR1B which represent their current positions. I am storing those values in array (k[] and z[]). Keys 5 and 6 are used to access the values stored earlier so that I can move the motors between the two positions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have declared the arrays `k[]` and `z[]` to have just one element each. Therefore, it is likely that the values you write to `k[]` are overwriting the values for `z[]`, and the values for `z[]` are getting clobbered by other variables.

Comment: I am using two values. k[0] and k[1] similarly, z[0] and z[1].Its working for OCR1A then why not for OCR1B??

Comment: When you declare "int k[1]" that means you can only use the index [0]. When "t" or "n" are incremented in your code, "undefined behavior" ensues. In C/C++, this undefined behavior cannot be easily detected, although a static code analyzer may find this bug. The particular behavior you see is whatever the compiler ended up generating for "undefined behavior," and is not something you can rely on. You never reset "n" or "t," and they will wrap to negative at some point, in addition to overflowing the bounds of the arrays.

Comment: Problem solved. I was assuming that  K[1] will represent k[0] and k[1].

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Dave's answer, it is good to mention that `unsigned int k[1]` only declares (is that the right word here?) `k[0]` and not `k[1]`.

Likewise:

- another example: `unsigned int k[10]` declares `k[0]` .. `k[9]`;
- in general: `unsigned int k[n]` declares `k[0]` .. `k[n-1]` etc.

Comment: The `k[n+1] and k[0] .. k[n]` would make more sense as `k[n] and k[0] .. k[n-1]` since n is the number of elements defined by the user and n-1 the location of the last element of the array.

Comment: granted @alexan_e